# Material-UI CardContent not rendering the jump lines

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component that renders a Material-UI `Card`, it receives a string like this:

```
'This
is
a
test'
```

But it renders `'This is a test'` in one single line. I tried this:

```
<Card>
  <CardContent>
     <Typography noWrap>{value}</Typography>
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

and

```
<Card>
  <CardContent>
     {value}
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

both of them renders the value in a single line, however, if I `console.log(value);` then it shows the message as expected on the console.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to force the text to go to the next line on newline character:

```
<Typography whiteSpace="pre">
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]